# iOS UISwitches are acting in three states

Tags: ios, xcode, uiswitch

I have added a few switches to my app. My problem is that they seem to have three graphical representations instead of just on/off:

[image: Switches turned off]

[image: Switches in three states]

When I toggle any button then others (not all) kind of gray out... It happens both in simulator and iPhone.

Comment: You should show some code of how you are turning switches on/of, and how you are responding to their events. We can't do anything to help you with just those two images.

Comment: are you settings the states of the switches like isSelected or somethingn like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set `tintColor` explicitly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method